# meaning: cut across something

Tags: vocabulary

> (1) Support for environmental issues ***cuts across*** traditional party lines. ([Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/cut-across-sth?q=cut%20across))
>   (2) opinion on European integration still ***cuts*** clean ***across*** party lines ([Collins dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cut-across))

Are both examples’ ‘cuts across’ equivalent to ‘*is contrary to*’ or ‘*is against*’?

Comment: No, these two have different meanings. In (1), _cuts across_ could be glossed as "be shared among the parties".

Comment: The short answer is that *cuts across* contrasts with *follows*. A vote that does not follow party lines cuts across those lines (i.e., is independent of party affiliation).

Comment: [Aha!](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/8993/1597) Now I see why you were asking!

Comment: @StoneyB Yes, that’s what. Today’s chart is the combination, as always is, of your persuasive knack and intuition. Thank you. And [here](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=2893645) is the very useful words that I needed, just now printed for perusal. By the way, is this chart from your own drawing?

Comment: Yes, that was the fun part!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both involve the same metaphor of cutting across existing natural lines of cleavage, as when we speak of cutting *across the grain* of wood or meat:

[image: Across the grain]
<sub>The flank steak image is from [theenchantedcook.blogspot.com](http://theenchantedcook.blogspot.com/2010/10/small-plates-lunch.html), the saw image is from [cmtutensili.com](http://www.cmtutensili.com/show_items.asp?pars=SB~291~2).</sub>

When we speak of issues or votes cutting *across party lines* we understand 'party lines' to be the 'lines' which divide the parties. On most issues people's attitudes *follow* party lines:
[image: With party lines]
But some issues divide differently: they cut *across* party lines:
[image: Across party lines]
Note that the 'party lines' we speak of here are not the same thing as 'the party line': the official position a party takes on a particular issue and its rhetorical 'line' of argument for supporting it. When an issue cuts *across party lines* it is not (necessarily) contrary to the parties' positions on the issue; it is 'contrary to' the usual lines of division between parties.